# How to record screen with zoom in high quality?

Tags: screen-casting

Is there some way to record Windows screen with zoom in high quality? Like in this video:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 options:

1. find a software that supports recording with a zoom-in
2. on Windows there is the screen magifier (I hope there is something similar on Mac?) which can be used to magnify the relevant screen part
3. you record the video normally and then edit in post

If you go for the first option, it's easy to find several screen recording applications with Google, I tried the terms "screen recorder" "zoom-in" (just usign "zoom" spoils the search results with many hits for the Zoom meeting app. So use "zoom-in" with quotes). I can't recommend any software in particular.

My preferred method would be to do it in post, but that's a personal preference and of course your video editor has to support it. The feature, which you need, may be called a "crop" effect, whereas the zoom effect will animate the process of zooming in or out. Anyway, when you want to do it in post, make sure you can record a higher resolution than the output resolution, e.g. record in 4k and output to HD. However editing 4k video requires either fast hardware or a good video editor that can work with proxy files or similar resource saving alternatives.

That said, the edit-in-post option takes some effort. Option 1 or 2 may be the more economic way for you.